# how do you check an input in java is a certain word or character

Tags: java

I have this code:

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the first number");
String l =reader.next();
String[] a = new String[2];

a[0] = l ;
a[1] = "5";

if((String) a[0] == "5" )
{
    System.out.println("hey");
}
```

however if I enter "5" as my input, "hey" is not printed how do I get it so that I can use an if statment to see if what is entered is a certain character or word

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `a[0].equals("5")`, `==` is just checking if they're the same object rather than string content.

Answer (score 0):

You should to compare array member with equals method, regarding to that is the String.

You should to use this:

```
if(a[0].equals("5") )
{
    System.out.println("hey");
}
```

instead of

```
if((String) a[0] == "5" )
{
    System.out.println("hey");
}
```

In that case you will check content, not the reference.

Answer (score 0):

### Use nextInt() to get integer

```
Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the first number");
int l =reader.nextInt();
if(l == 5 )
{
   System.out.println("hey");
}
```